# sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats table showing incorrect execution count when executing stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in C# and when I select `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`, it shows that the code ran the query 10 times. I debugged my code and I used `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` and `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` to clear SQL cache before execute the query again and after I step into `command.ExecuteReader()`, I executed the query below

```
SELECT TOP 50 
    d.object_id,
    d.database_id,
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) As 'Name',
    d.cached_time,
    d.last_execution_time,
    d.last_worker_time,
    d.total_elapsed_time,
    d.total_worker_time,
    d.total_elapsed_time / d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
    d.last_elapsed_time,
    d.execution_count
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d
WHERE 
    d.database_id = DB_ID()
```

It showed that the code executed the stored procedure 10 times.

I checked my code and I'm 100% sure that there isn't any code calling this stored procedure.

I tried to execute the stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio then ran the query above and it showed one execution count

I'm using .Net framework 4.7.2, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Hangfire.

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[Test_Select]", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", number);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (SqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
```

My stored procedure is really simple.

```
SELECT col
FROM TABLE
WHERE number = @number
```

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at connection string.  You may be connected to a different MDF file.

Comment: I've checked and i'm not connected to a different mdf file.

Comment: The SQL is using table sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats while the stored procedure is using table TABLE.

Comment: I compared the last_elapsed_time and total_elapsed_time between executing the query in management studio and in code. both show the same time. Also, I created a new project using the same connection string and settings and it shows one count. I thought maybe issue with my code. so I used the sql profiler and it shows that the stored procedure has been executed once and the sys.dm_exec_proedure_stats show 10 times.

Comment: Did you run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, I did and it shows 1 count.

Comment: The only time I see issuers like this is if the wrong database is being used, or the WHERE in one case is using an integer for ID and another case using a string.